# Microsoft Navision Value Entry Table sales amount(actual) incorrect when joining to another table

Tags: sql-server-2014, microsoft-dynamics, navision

Hi guys if you familiar with Microsoft Dynamics Navision 2013 and its tables 
then you might be able to help me

Hi

I am using Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2013 , SQL server 2014 , Tableau Desktop

I have created a new table which contains data from the Excise Rate, Location , Item and Item Unit of Measure tables in order to calculate Transfer Excise. Transfer Excise is Tax that we pay when our wine gets transported from one Warehouse to another. I did a Left Join to the Value Entry table which contains all item related transactions as I need the Invoice Quantity column to calculate Transfer Excise. This is how I calculate Transfer Excise: (Invoiced Quantity / Litre Conversion Factor * Unit Rate) = Transfer Excise. With this approach I did get the desired result , see the SQL script to get the Transfer Excise

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.[Entry No_] ,    
    a.[Starting Date],    
    b.[Posting Date],    
    b.[Item No_],    
    b.[Invoiced Quantity],    
    b.[Sales Amount (Actual)],    
    a.[Litre Conversion Factor],    
    a.[Unit Rate] ,    
    b.[Location Code],    
    a.[Excise Location],    
    a.[Excise Type Code],    
    a.[Unit Of Measure Code]    
FROM [Spier Live$Value Entry] b    
LEFT JOIN [Transfer Excise Tbl] a
    ON a.[No_] = b.[Item No_]    
    AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]    
    AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > -365    
    AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) < 0    
WHERE b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26'    
    AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA','EXSA')    
    AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <>0    
GROUP BY b.[Entry No_] ,a.[Starting Date], b.[Posting Date], b.[Item No_], b.[Invoiced Quantity],
    b.[Sales Amount (Actual)], a.[Litre Conversion Factor], a.[Unit Rate] ,
    b.[Location Code], a.[Excise Location], a.[Excise Type Code], a.[Unit Of Measure Code]
```

With all this done , the sales amount (Actual) value changes which should not be the case. Someone told me that it might be the Left Join causing the Sales Amount(Actual) to change. I cannot change the script because then the Transfer Excise Value will be incorrect or is there another or better way of writing this query so that the sales amount (Actual) and Transfer Excise values will remain the same. Oh the reason for the way i wrote the query is because i want to get the Unit Rate for each item transaction.

I really don't know why this script is changing the sales amount (Actual)

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what are you asking? your script is not a `modify` script.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is not in the join. Actually, it does not make sense to group results on amount fields like "Sales Amount (Actual)" and "Unit Rate".
I suppose what you want to do is sum the sales amount and invoiced quantity over all related value entries in an item transaction. Then you should remove these fields from GROUP BY clause and add a sum on them:

```
SELECT
  ...
  SUM([Invoiced Quantity]),
  SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)])
```

Then group results by [Item Ledger Entry No.] instead of [Entry No.]. Entry No. in value entry is an identifier of a financial (cost) transaction, while item ledger entry no. actually identifies an item-related activity.